# Reflection in namespace php

Tags: php, reflection, namespaces

```
namespace foo;
class a
{
private $bar;
public $baz;
protected $alpha
}

$reflect=new \ReflectionClass('a');
$properties=$reflect->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED);
```

It will return `ReflectionProperty` class not found Fatal error Where $properties is array of object of `ReflectionProperty`. Why does not it resolved to global space automatically? where as DOM related class do that implicitly. if `ReflectionProperty` class is `use`d in namespace it works though. but why not implicitly it happends?

Comment: Please fix the other problems with your code, such that we can see the "ReflectionProperty class not found Fatal error"; if you can.

Comment: @salthe I am not sure what problem you are referring to.

Comment: I dont understand why my question is get down voted. what is wrong with my question?

Comment: Copy-and-pasting your code above, which is supposed to display the described behaviour, results in a [Parse Error](http://so.viperpad.com/4RqLGU). Fixing this parse error results in a ReflectionException stating [Class a does not exist](http://so.viperpad.com/aHODkH). Fixing this exception results in [Fatal error: Class 'foo\ReflectionProperty' not found](http://so.viperpad.com/SPicS4). This last error most closely resembles your described problem, however the class names differ (mine has the namespace, your description does not). All of this is work that we should not have to do, to help you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

class in namespace will be preceeded by namespace name and global property needs to be preceeded by slash(\). [use manual](https://www.php.net/language.namespaces.rules)
Try this

```
namespace foo;
class a
{
private $bar;
public $baz;
protected $alpha;
}

$reflect=new \ReflectionClass('\\foo\\a');
$properties=$reflect->getProperties(\ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED);
```

Comment: Can we declare one `namespace` per project? I mean all files in the project will have same `namespace`...

Answer (score 1):

Relative classnames (those not starting with `\\`) are always resolved first against the current namespace and then against every aliased identifier (via `use`). This means especially, that if you don't define a concrete namespace yourself you are within the global one, which means, that `\Bar` and `Bar` refers the same class. But if you are within a namespace `Foo` they differs (`\Bar <==> Bar == \Foo\Bar`).

You can find a [detailed explanation in the manual](http://php.net/language.namespaces.rules). In the ["namespace basics" section](http://php.net/language.namespaces.basics) of the manual you can find the idea behind this: It's like a filesystem. If you are in the root, `cat /etc/passwd` and `cat etc/passwd` are the same, but not, if you change the workdirectory.

(Beside: It should be `$reflect=new \ReflectionClass('\\foo\\a');`, or `$reflect=new \ReflectionClass(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\a');`)